# Add image to pdf through xsl-fo using XML attribute value

Tags: xml, xpath, xsl-fo

I'm making a PDF from an XMl doc using XSL-FO. I need to import images using their names that are inside the XML doc.

Example XML:

```
<newAlbums>
   <album cover="blaimage.jpg"/>
</newAlbums>
```

I need to do this through a similar statement:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="({})/>
```

What XPath do I need to put inside the src attribute to import the image?
Thanks for the help this has been killing me.

Answer (score 9):

It will basically be `<fo:external-graphic src="{concat('url(', /newAlbums/album/@cover, ')')}">`. The exact XPath expression will depend on your XML. For example, you will most likely have more than one album element, so `/newAlbums/album[1]/@cover` or similar will be required.

Comment: Thanks! It wokred perfectly!!! Yes my XPath is pretty good so I new how to do that part, I'm just not so used to XSL-FO.